# Request.getPart is called without multipart jsp

Tags: java, jsp

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml

I am getting this error above when i try to add image to my project

MY html is

```
<form action="../include/crud.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" style="display:none;" name="photo" />
</form>
```

My crud.jsp is

```
<%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ include file="dbconfig.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.swing.*" %>
<%@page 
    import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"
    import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException"
    import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"
    import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"


    %>

<% 

    Part filePart = request.getPart("photo"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
    String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;



        String act = request.getParameter("btncrud");
        if (act == null) {
            //no button has been selected
        } else if (act.equals("Add")) {
            //Add button was pressed


            String add_disbursement = "INSERT INTO photo_table "
                                + "(ri_photo,ri_photo_name)"
                                + " VALUES (?,?)"; 

            preparedStatement.setBlob(1,fileContent);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,fileName);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } else if (act.equals("Update")) {
            //update button was pressed

        } else {
            //someone has altered the HTML and sent a different value!

        }         
%>
```

1. How to get rid of the error
2. How to save photo file in database as medium blob

**FYI**

Column `ri_photo` is of type mediumblob

`UPDATE`

ADDED `cos-multipart.jar` and `import=" com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest"` still same error

How to add `@MultipartConfig` in JSP page

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs whenever the request body size is greater than default.

If you want custom size, or greater than default, you need to override the multipart-config settings in web.xml
you can refer following:

```
<multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>*size in bytes*</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>*size in bytes*</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>*size in bytes*</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: is the file `web.xml` auto generated?i look for it in `web\WEB-INF` nothing is there except lib folder

Comment: I would suggest to go for servlet java file instead of jsp to do java related stuff, like DB crud operation, as i dont see anything else, like html code, in your crud.jsp, In that way you can specify @MultipartConfig in your java file without web.xml. And that way your application will also comply with Servelt Specs, which demands web.xml, or related annotations in java Servlet code.